# Combine two .each jquery functions for sharepoint

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, each

I have two Jquery functions that each work independently on a sharepoint page - however I'd like for them to work together - both 'if' statements must be statisfied in order for an action to take place e.g. IF the right list name is found AND the right item is in that list THEN hide that row.

```
$(".ms-WPHeader").each(function(){

var valx = $(this).text();

    if(valx=="ListName"){
        alert("found");
    }
});


$(".ms-vb-title").each(function(){

var val = $(this).text();

    if(val=="this item"){
        $(this).parents('tr:first').hide();

    }
});
```

I've new to Jquery and still new to the structure - I've searched everywhere - hope you can help?

Additional code snippet shows relationship between WPHeader and vb-title:

```
<td id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2" valign="top">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" toplevel="">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="ms-WPHeader">
<td id="WebPartTitleWPQ2" style="width:100%;" title="ListName">
<h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-WPTitle">
<a href="/test/Lists/Content%20List/AllItems.aspx" tabindex="0" accesskey="W">
<nobr>
<span>ListName</span>
<span id="WebPartCaptionWPQ2"></span>
</nobr>
</a>
</h3>
</td>
<td valign="middle" style="width:10px;padding-right:2px;">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="" valign="top">
<div id="WebPartWPQ2" style="" allowexport="false" allowdelete="false" width="100%" haspers="false" webpartid="9cc3ce88-c0c6-40d4-84a6-0a14d4bfe3ed">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<script>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<iframeid="FilterIframe1" width="0" height="0" filterlink="http://dab:23292/test/Content%20Library/Template%20page.aspx?Filter=1&View=%7b9CC3CE88%2dC0C6%2d40D4%2d84A6%2d0A14D4BFE3ED%7d" title="Hidden frame to filter list" style="display:none" name="FilterIframe1" src="javascript:false;">
<table id="{33B3ECBF-66DA-41AD-811D-F3A2D7F644F7}-{9CC3CE88-C0C6-40D4-84A6-0A14D4BFE3ED}" class="ms-listviewtable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" dir="None" o:webquerysourcehref="http://dab:23292/test/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001&XMLDATA=1&RowLimit=0&List={33B3ECBF-66DA-41AD-811D-F3A2D7F644F7}&View={9CC3CE88-C0C6-40D4-84A6-0A14D4BFE3ED}" summary="Content Meta List">
<tbody>
<tr class="ms-viewheadertr" valign="TOP" style="display: none;">
<tr class="">
<tr class="ms-alternating">
<td class="ms-vb2">
<td class="ms-vb2">
<td class="ms-vb-title" height="100%">
<table id="7" class="ms-unselectedtitle" height="100%" cellspacing="0" surl="" uis="512" cid="0x0100363A3EFC8C275E49B25A04F063C9FADB" ctype="Item" ms="0" csrc="" hcd="" couid="" otype="0" icon="icgen_gif||" ext="" type="" perm="0x7fffffffffffffff" dref="test/Lists/Content List" url="/test/Lists/Content%20List/7_.000" ctxname="ctx1" onmouseover="OnItem(this)">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ms-vb" width="100%">
<a target="_self" onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/test/Lists/Content%20List/DispForm.aspx?ID=7" onfocus="OnLink(this)">this item
</a>
</td>
<td class="">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
```

Comment: can we se some html markup!! not sure what controls the classes are on

Comment: Hi Baz1nga - Both the functions are on a Sharepoint page in a CEWP inside <script> tags. Its a large page - not sure where I can paste it here.

Comment: Hi Baz1nga - I've added so more markup - hope this can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that *ms-vb-title* is the class name of list items and *ms-WPHeader* is inside this list somewhere, here is the proper code:

```
$(".ms-vb-title").each(function(){
    var val = $(this).text();
    if(val === "this item" && $(this).parents("ul").find(".ms-WPHeader").text() === "ListName") {
        $(this).parents('tr:first').hide();
    }
});
```

If the element with class *ms-WPHeader* is outside the list but the amount match the amount of lists, you can try with `index()`:

```
$(".ms-vb-title").each(function(){
    var val = $(this).text();
    if(val === "this item") {
        var oParentList = $(this).parents("ul");
        var oHeader = $(".ms-WPHeader").eq(oParentList.index());
        if (oHeader.text() === "ListName") {
            $(this).parents('tr:first').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit**: seeing your actual markup, here is something that should work better:

```
$(".ms-vb-title").each(function(){
    var val = $.trim($(this).find("a").text());
    if(val === "this item" && $(".ms-WPHeader").find("td").first().attr("title") === "ListName") {
        $(this).parents('tr:first').hide();
    }
});
```

**Edit**: assuming you got amount of `.ms-WPHeader` equal to `.ms-vb-title` and in same order, you can use the index:

```
$(".ms-vb-title").each(function(index){
    var val = $.trim($(this).find("a").text());
    if(val === "this item" && $(".ms-WPHeader").eq(index).find("td").first().attr("title") === "ListName") {
        $(this).parents('tr:first').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Shadow Wizard - I've tried the code and still trying variations - I think the class relationships are not clear in my post - I've reposted some code that may help - eitherway I think your code will work - I just doint know enough to get it working - yet. If you can help further than much appreciated - i feel i am almost there

Comment: Not quite there yet - if I switch $(".ms-vb-title") with $(".ms-WPHeader") on line 1 in your edit above "val" will return the correct ListName - I just cant work out how to get access to the ms-vb-title. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Sorry got to go now - will try later to test it on jsFiddle, until then feel free to mess around and you might get it right eventually.

Comment: Many thanks Shadow for your support - I still can't crack it - I dont 100% understand the DOM/classes. I will keep trying! Thanks again.

Comment: Well, [this simplified version](http://jsfiddle.net/sWtMG/) works just fine - hiding the row as expected.

Comment: It works! However my learn from your help is that there are more than one ms-WPHeader in the table (the example i gave was 4 or more down in the table - i just didnt think about highlighting that) - I understand that I now need to work out how to remove this row with a ms-WPHeader that is amongst others, and lower down the table (or keep it to the first list on the page).

Comment: Spot on - perfect! Thank you. This removes the row in the first list. In a similar scenario - how can I select the item in the last list instead? changing index to -1 doesn't appear to work?

Comment: Got it - it was "-index" - thanks for all your support - really much appreciated. I've learnt a lot - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var found = false;
$(".ms-WPHeader").each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == "ListName")
        found = true;
});

$(".ms-vb-title").each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == "this item" && found == true)
        $(this).parents('tr:first').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks OptimusCrime - but for some reason this doesnt work - true is set independently - so the desired AND doesnt happen